# Regex for partial path

Tags: java, regex, parsing, re2, sumologic

I have paths like these (single lines):

```
/
/abc
/def/
/ghi/jkl
/mno/pqr/
/stu/vwx/yz
/abc/def/ghi/jkl
```

I just need patterns that match up to the third "/".  In other words, paths containing just "/" and up to the first 2 directories.  However, some of my directories end with a "/" and some don't.  So the result I want is:

```
/
/abc
/def/
/ghi/jkl
/mno/pqr/
/stu/vwx/
/abc/def/
```

So far, I've tried `(\/|.*\/)` but this doesn't get the path ending without a "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(/([^/]+){0,2}\/?)$
```

To break it down

- `^` is the start of the string
- `{0,2}` means repeat the previous between 0 and 2 times.
- Then it ends with an optional slash by using a `?`
- String end is `$` so it doesn't match longer strings.
- `()` Around the whole thing to capture it.

But I'll point out that the is almost always the wrong answer for directory matching. Some directories have special meaning, like /../.. which actually goes *up* two directories, not down. Better to use the systems directory API instead for more robust results.

Comment: Note that you don't have to escape the forward slash. Your regex uses 3 capturing group where is misses the closing parenthesis for the outer group. You could omit the 2 outer capturing groups and make the inner one a non capturing group. This pattern `[^/]+` will also [match](https://regex101.com/r/pkirQi/1) a line break character and the `$` is missing where you are referring to in your explanation.

Comment: Bad syntax. Parenthesis don't match. please fix.

Comment: If you're reading this 3 years after I wrote it, then you should pay special attention to the part where I said not to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend this pattern:

```
/^(\/[^\/]+){0,2}\/?$/gm
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://regexr.com/422km)</kbd>

It works like this:

- `^` searches for the beginning of a line
- `(\/[^\/]+)` searches for a path element

  - `(` starts a group
  - `\/` searches for a slash
  - `[^\/]+` searches for some non-slash characters
- `{0,2}` says, that 0 to 2 of those path elements should be found
- `\/?` allows trailling slashes
- `$` searches for the end of the line

Use these modifiers:

- `g` to search for several matches within the input
- `m` to treat every line as a separate input

Answer (score 2):

You need a pattern like `^(\/\w+){0,2}\/?$`, it checks that you have *(`/` and name)* no more than 2 times and that it can end with `/`

Details :

- `^` : beginning of the string
- `(\/\w+)` : slash (escaped) and word-char, all in a group
- `{0,2}` the group can be 0/1/2 times
- `\/?` : slash (escaped) can be 0 or 1 time

<kbd>[Online DEMO](https://ideone.com/l8L5U8)</kbd>
<kbd>[Regex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/2j9lMg/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Your regex `(\/|.*\/)` uses an alternation which matches either a forward slash or any characters 0+ times greedy followed by matching a forward slash.

So in for example `/ghi/jkl`, the first match will be the first forward slash. Then this part `.*` of the next pattern will match from the first `g` until the end of the string. The engine will backtrack to last forward slash to fullfill the whole `.*\/` pattern.

The trailing `jkl` can not be matched anymore by neither patterns of the alternation.

Note that you don't have to escape the forward slash.

You could use:

`^/(?:\w+/?){0,2}$`

In Java:

```
String regex = "^/(?:\\w+/?){0,2}$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zKcV1W/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `/` Match forward slash
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\w+` Match 1+ word characters (If you want to match more than `\w` you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add to that what you want match)
  - `/?` Match optional forward slash
- `){0,2}` Close non capturing group and repeat 0 - 2 times
- `$` End of the string